# Add Style on image object using JavaScript in Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to add z-index on the image. I also used setAttribute but style not working. Please figure out the issue

```
// Hero image
var heroReady = false;
var heroImage = new Image();
heroImage.onload = function () {
    heroReady = true;
};

heroImage.setAttribute("src", "img/car.png");
heroImage.setAttribute("style", "z-index:5;");
```

Comment: When you say, you are trying to add a z-index, are you using a canvas to draw this image? Or are you referring to a CSS style?

Comment: With the given code, your image is never appended to the document, `heroReady` doesn't  refer to anything and the [canvas] tag is irrelevant.

Comment: @Canvas Yes I'm using Canvas

Comment: @Kaiido the code is working fine to me.. just I need to apply z-index

Comment: Place yourself in our position : If we just copy-paste the given code, we won't be able to reproduce anything, we'll just have two global variables : `heroReady` and `heroImage`, the former being a boolean, set to true when the later, a never appended `Image` has load. We can only make assumptions on what you do beside it, and where your error probably lies.

Comment: @MuhammadRehman Ok if you are using a canvas, just draw the background images first and then draw the foreground images, so for example `canvas.drawImage(backgroundSprite,0,0); canvas,drawImage(heroImage, 100, 100);` You layer you images so the first images you draw are always behind you draw the foreground images last

Comment: @Canvas Thanks for the help.. I really appreciate it. now it's work fine for me

Answer (score 2):

You should use "style". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

```
heroImage.style.zIndex = "5";
```

Here's [an example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_zindex) to play with.

Snippet:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("something");
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.width = "200px";
div.style.height = "200px";
div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
div.style.zIndex = "2";

function onClick() {
  (div.style.zIndex == "2") ? div.style.zIndex = "0" : div.style.zIndex = "2";
}
```

```css
#another {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
}

button {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="something">Something</div>
<div id="another">Another</div>
<button onclick="onClick()">Change zIndex</button>
```

Comment: He wasn't asking for this, I think... but it's more right to do this.